# Como validar os dados usando beforeSend com Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de mensagens com data inicial e final de cada mensagem, so que antes de enviar os dados via Ajax, quero validar alguns campos. Fiz boa parte, o único problema é que quando termino a validação a página é recarregada, impedindo do usuário realizar a correção. Help!

```
form.ajaxSubmit({
        url: 'themes/intranet_fametro/ajax/' + callback + '.ajax.php',
        data: {callback_action:callback_action},
        dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                if (callback_action == 'criar-mensagem') {
                    if(dataInicial < dataAtual){
                        $("#load").html("Data inicial errada, insira uma data posterior.");
                    }
                    else if(dataFinal < dataInicial){
                        $("#load").html("Data final incorreta, insira uma data posterior.");
                    }

                }
            },
            success: function(data){
                window.location.href = 'mensagem';
            }

        });
```

Comment: Creio que no `beforeSend` não é um bom canto para validar..
Mas se colocar um `return false` dentro do `beforeSend` CREIO que pode para seu Ajax isso eu não testei.
Não seria melhor validar antes de enviar seu Ajax ?

Comment: Sim, validei antes de enviar. Obrigado pela atenção !